# Toggling button text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have an HTML button created and I want to toggle the text that is displayed in the button between two text using Javascript/JQuery. How do I do this?

Currently, I have:

```
<button onclick="showAll();" class="collapse-classes">
    <span class="button-text">Show</span>
</button>
```

The button starts off by displaying "Show" and then switch to "Hide" when clicked and then switch to "Show"  when clicked again and onward. I tried changing the value of the tag but it doesn't change the text displayed. Can anyone help with the script? thanks

Comment: What actually have you tried?

Comment: Both the answers have the text toggling after clicking it twice. I would like the text to toggle after clicking it immediately, is there a way that can happen?

Comment: have you ever done your work yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `onclick`. Just bind an event handler.

Here's something you can work with:

```
$('.collapse-classes').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.toggleClass('show');

    if ($this.hasClass('show')) {
        $this.text('Show');
    } else {
        $this.text('Hide');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your DOM tree

```
$('.collapse-classes').click(function() {

    var span = $(this).find('span');

    if(span.text() == "Show"){
        span.text("Hide");
    } else {
        span.text("Show");
    }

});
```