# jQuery: Change button text on click

Tags: jquery

After seeing [Toggling button text in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148093/toggling-button-text-in-jquery) this question, I tried to re create it in my situation but can't seem to have it work.

Here is a fiddle of what I've done: http://jsfiddle.net/V4u5X/

```
$('.SeeMore2').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('SeeMore');
    if($this.hasClass('.SeeMore2')){
        $this.text('See More');         
    } else {
        $this.text('See Less');
    }
});
```

It seems to only ever run the if statement once. What am I missing?

Comment: Don't put a `.` in the argument to `hasClass`.

Comment: If I do that it actually doesn't change the text at all

Comment: You toggle the seeMore class but never deals with seemore2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button text toggle in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652835/button-text-toggle-in-jquery)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
$('.SeeMore2').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('SeeMore2');
    if($this.hasClass('SeeMore2')){
        $this.text('See More');         
    } else {
        $this.text('See Less');
    }
});
```

This should do it. You have to make sure you toggle the correct class and take out the "." from the hasClass

http://jsfiddle.net/V4u5X/2/

Comment: *facepalm* I misunderstood how the argument worked for .toggleClass. I assumed that you would specify a seperate class within the (). In my original it still has the class of SeeMore2, now that I look at it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Doesn't work on archives which contain multiple entries with more than 1 instance of the same button. @Scherf

Answer (score 7):

try this,
this javascript code to change text all time to click button.http://jsfiddle.net/V4u5X/2/

html code

```
<button class="SeeMore2">See More</button>
```

javascript

```
$('.SeeMore2').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('SeeMore2');
        if($this.hasClass('SeeMore2')){
            $this.text('See More');         
        } else {
            $this.text('See Less');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

In HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="AddButton" onclick="AddButtonClick()" class="btn btn-success btn-block ">Add</button>
```

In Jquery write this function:

```
    function AddButtonClick(){ 
      //change text from add to Update
      $("#AddButton").text('Update');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> its work short code

`$('.SeeMore2').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this).toggleClass('SeeMore2');
       if($(this).hasClass('SeeMore2'))
               {
             $(this).text('See More');

           } else {
             $(this).text('See Less');
               }
});`

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $(this).html("the new text");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
    $('.SeeMore2').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('SeeMore2');
        if($this.hasClass('SeeMore2')){
            $this.text('See More');         
        } else {
            $this.text('See Less');
        }
});
```