# Replace button text onclick JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm trying to change button text on button click so that the text changes from 'Copy' to 'Copied!' as part of a custom clipboard setup. Here is the code I'm using:

**HTML:**

`<button id="copyButton2">Copy</button>`

**JS:**

```
<script>
 jQuery(".copyButton2").click(function () {
            jQuery(this).text(function(i, v){
               return v === 'Copy' ? 'Copied!' : 'Copy'
            })
        });
</script>
```

which doesn't appear to be working correctly.

I have also tried modifying [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365386/jquery-change-button-text-on-click) to no avail. Is there an obvious reason why this isn't working?

Comment: use `#` for id `.` for class

Answer (score 4):

You've set `copyButton2` as the `id` of the element, yet you're using a class selector. You need to prefix the selector with `#`, not `.`

Also note that, depending on where you're running the jQuery code, you may also need to include a document.ready handler. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#copyButton2").click(function() {
    $(this).text(function(i, v) {
      return v === 'Copy' ? 'Copied!' : 'Copy'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="copyButton2">Copy</button>
```

Comment: This question must be close as a `typo`.

Comment: The selector typo may not be the only issue, as I stated in the answer the lack of a document.ready handler could be a factor too

Comment: Sorry, +1 instead :)

Comment: Typo was a rookie error on my behalf :/ and document handler also required - thanks Rory!

Comment: @JackVanstone no problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Please use id selector ("#copyButton2") instead of class selector as you have used id for the close button.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a javascript solution while we're at it.

```
<script> 
  var testDiv = document.getElementById('test');

  testDiv.onclick = function(){
    testDiv.innerHTML = "Copied!"
  };
</script>
```

Comment: This isn't quite the same. The OPs original toggles the value on successive clicks. This sets it to `Copied!` only